# Getting Chosen.JS values back in to field from Database after page update[Classic ASP]

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic, jquery-chosen

So I have a form that is using a chosen multiple select field. The user is able to edit this page and save to a DB, I want to set it up in a way so when the user gets to this edit page, all of those multiple selects that wrote to the db earler will display on this edit page. I am able to get one value to show up but im not sure how I can get multiple values, and what format the chosen field needs to display these values. Thanks for any help or advice. Due to the length of my page I will include the portion that is getting info from the Database.

```
<select name="Form-Dropdown-businessUnit" multiple id="Form-Dropdown-businessUnit" form="Form">
  <option value="consumer" <%If (Not isNull((RS_Edit.Fields.Item("Business_Unit").Value))) Then If ("consumer" = CStr((RS_Edit.Fields.Item("Business_Unit").Value))) Then Response.Write("selected=""selected""") : Response.Write("")%>>Consumer</option>
  <option value="business" <%If (Not isNull((RS_Edit.Fields.Item("Business_Unit").Value))) Then If ("business" = CStr((RS_Edit.Fields.Item("Business_Unit").Value))) Then Response.Write("selected=""selected""") : Response.Write("")%>>Business</option>
  <option value="cfs" <%If (Not isNull((RS_Edit.Fields.Item("Business_Unit").Value))) Then If ("cfs" = CStr((RS_Edit.Fields.Item("Business_Unit").Value))) Then Response.Write("selected=""selected""") : Response.Write("")%>>CFS</option>
</select>
```

What I have listed in my DB in my Business Unit Table:
consumer, business, cfs (one cell)

So it seems that its not able to check the logic because the data in the db is in a comma delimited list, there is no consumer,business,cfs conditional check and I would need to create an intermediary table that one pull one value at a time, i.e. Consumer, then Business, that would check this against the logic in my ASP?

Comment: Some code of what you've got so far would be great. Also is this classic asp or asp.net?

Comment: Code listed above, sorry this is classic asp